# C : Nothing to be done for 'all' Hello word

Tags: c, eclipse, console, printf, program-entry-point

I have the problem that I would write a "hello word"
but when I *push at play*, it say "Nothing to be done for 'all'.
Whats wrong ?!

```
 #include <stdio.h>

static char read()
{
    char c;
    printf("Nennen Sie einen Namen: ");
    scanf("%c", &c);

    return c;
}
int main()
{
    char r = read();
    printf("Sie heißen %r.", r);
    return 0;
}
```

only this code is in my test.c

Comment: Check your makefile first.

Comment: "Push at play"? Like on a tape deck? With high-speed dubbing?

Comment: `printf("Sie heißen %r.", r);` --> `printf("Sie heißen %c", r);`

Comment: @KerrekSB why not on XboX?

Comment: perhaps new build is not cleaning the old `test.o` file.

Comment: _Push at play_ hahaha, that white equilateral triangle in a green circle?

Comment: @rakeb.void I assume it's side-facing triangle?

Comment: What is `%r` ?  I think the op got something very wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, hahaha yes, meanwhile I up voted this question as it made my day!

Comment: Probably your makefile or compilation configuration (in case you're using an IDE).

Comment: @rakeb.void: No, that's "eject". It creates a core dump.

Comment: What is `read()`?  The POSIX version requires some parameters, and it returns the number of bytes read, not the value of any particular one.  Also, it's not ordinarily declared in `stdio.h`.

Comment: In eclipse, check your "Run As" configuration. It may be pointing to somewhere else. Most definetly your problem has to do with wrong configuration of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You used a invalid format specifier `%r`, the format specifier for `char` character printing is `%c`.

If you were trying to print the the numerical value of you `char` variable, us `%d`.

You can find more information about `printf()`[here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)